# XPath syntax error thrown when using evaluate() method

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Still i am getting the below error

```
Error at xsl:param on line 6 of file:/E:/saxon/parastyleText.xsl:
  XPST0003: XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 6 in {...le/@w:val[matches(., c
oncat...}:
    Invalid character '^' in expression
Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

Modified XSL:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">

    <xsl:param name="styleName" select="'articletitle'"/>
    <xsl:param name="tagName" select="'//w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val[matches(., concat('^(',$styleName,')$'),'i')]]'"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="saxon:evaluate($tagName)" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please dont reply that, quotes will make 'tagName' as string and remove those quotes. This value will be actually passed from java as a string , tats y for testing purpose i have passed this xpath as string.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use exactly? Does its documentation say it supports the EXSLT `dyn:evaluate` function? And why you mention XSLT version 3.0? EXSLT is not related to XSLT version 3.0, it was an effort to define extension to XSLT 1.0. XSLT version 3.0 has its own approach http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dynamic-xpath at dynamic path evaluation that is independent of EXSLT. And of course you would need a processor that supports XSLT version 3.0.

Comment: I doubt that any XSLT **2.0** processor supports EXSLT, not to speak about any XSLT 3.0 processor. In XSLT 3.0 you may want to use `<xsl:evaluate>` -- see it defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate

Comment: @Martin Honnen - I have been using saxon xslt processor. Documentation of Version 9.1.0.8 says it supports evaluate() method. Me mentioning 'XSLT version 3.0' is a mistake. I have corrected it. Please have a look...

Comment: Pippa, I posted an answer showing how to use a Saxon 9.1 specific `evaluate` function. I don't think the EXSLT one is supported.

Comment: @Martin Honnen - I tried my code with ur answer. Still it shows error. Updated with recent coding. pls check.

Comment: It is a completely different error now, a syntax error in the stylesheet. I think you should post a new question, showing the input XML you have and explaining the result you want, then people can suggest how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the online documentation http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.1/extensions/functions.html Saxon 9.1 supports [an `evaluate` function in the Saxon namespace `http://saxon.sf.net/`](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.1/extensions/functions/evaluate.html). So with Saxon 9.1 try `<xsl:value-of select="saxon:evaluate($tagName)" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>`. Of course you can move the namespace declaration up to the `xsl:stylesheet` element if you want, I just put it on the `xsl:value-of` in this post for a short but complete sample of code.

Also note that with your variable named `tagName` it is likely that you simply have a single element name, in that case it might suffice to use `<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() eq $tagName]"/>`.